# 4 Pins Potentiometer (Replacement)

Tags: potentiometer, joystick

I am trying to repair a very expensive manlift joystick.

It has 4 pins total, three like a normal rotary potentiometer and then a fourth across from the other three pins.

It is PEO 284-04378 Type EJ pot. It has another number stamped "5k 1342"

The company not produce it more and I'm looking if there is something similar to do the same work I was looking for P271-DS21BR10K but is 10K would that affect?[image]

Comment: Please correct your question title - ALLCAPS is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems almost certain that you are looking for a "center tapped potentiometer" If you search using that term, you should be able to find a replacement. It seems likely that the pictured pot is 5K ohms. You may or may not be able to use a different value. You can not find the correct value, you could try a different value and see what happens. Trying 10K rather than 1K would seem to me to be the safest thing to try if you can not find 5K.

Answer (score 0):

It may affect. But you can use any other 10K POT which would fit in, and of course with the right connections.

Comment: Thanks, I will still waiting if someone can know about a similar potentiometer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found that one that seem to have the same number and is 5k too I hope that work, thanks
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Duep.png)